# Model-View-Controller-Service shared flat expenses interface

Tags: php, mvc

I'm new to php and OOP, and for learning I started writing an application that would help me and my flatmates to manage our expenses and debts to one another.

The full source is available at https://bitbucket.org/nicocool84/coloc-web/src. I tried to use the MVC(S) architecture without using a framework.

The project tree is as follows:

```
.
├── controllers
│   ├── DebtController.php
│   ├── DefaultController.php
│   └── UserController.php
├── models
│   ├── DebtList.php
│   ├── Debt.php
│   └── User.php
├── services
│   ├── Database.php
│   ├── DebtService.php
│   ├── RedirectService.php
│   └── UserService.php
├── views
│   ├── footer.php
│   ├── header_logged.php
│   ├── header_unlogged.php
│   ├── home_unlogged.php
│   ├── html_header.php
│   ├── jumbotron.php
│   └── list_debts.php
└── web
    ├── index.php
    └── .htaccess
```

`.htaccess` redirects all requests to `index.php` which decides which controller and which action to call based on the URI: `http://mysite.my/controller/action`.

To handle sessions, when a user is authenticated, I store a `User` instance with his details in `$_SESSION`. The related methods are stored in `UserService`, for instance `getCurrentName`. Is this a good practice? Should I create a `SessionService`? Should I do this completely differently?

Is creating a `DebtList` class to compute who owes what making any sense?

I know the HTML/CSS part is quite ugly, and I'm open to advice there too.

Thanks to anyone who will take the time to review it all.

Comment: You need to place the code you wish to have reviewed in your post.

Comment: Code reviews work best if you just post a small bit of code, reading through someones entire project is quite time consuming. for example you could start off by posting the DebtController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start

I opened your code in php storm and it says
Non-static method Database::getPdo() should not be called statically

Where you have code like this

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    $id = $_REQUEST['debt_id'];
    if (UserService::isLogged()) {
        if (DebtService::getPaidByFromId($id) == UserService::getCurrentUserId() or UserService::isAdmin()) {
            DebtService::deleteById($id);
            return DebtController::listAction();
        } else {
            RedirectService::goHome();
        }
    } else {
        RedirectService::goHome();
    }
}
```

I prefer to have a guard clause at the top, so you can easily see the outcome of the if/else without having to scroll to the end of the code

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    if (!UserService::isLogged()) {
        RedirectService::goHome();
    }

    // TODO what if debt_id doesn't exist, always check isset()
    $id = $_REQUEST['debt_id'];

    if (DebtService::getPaidByFromId($id) == UserService::getCurrentUserId() or UserService::isAdmin()) {
        DebtService::deleteById($id);
        return DebtController::listAction();
    } else {
        RedirectService::goHome();
    }        
}
```

Instead of this

```
$includes = array("controllers", "services", "models");

foreach ($includes as $dir) {
    foreach (glob("../" . $dir . "/*.php") as $file) {
        require $file;
    }
}
```

you might want to look at autoloading, it's not very hard to do
http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

In your templates you are doing

```
<?php echo $debt->getDescription(); ?>
```

Unless you know for sure there is no html or user editable content, 
you should really html escape it

```
<?php echo htmlentities($debt->getDescription()); ?>
```

Database service, take the config out of the service, and store it in a config file. otherwise you need to edit the code when you deploy to a different server.

Would a join work better here

```
// DebtService::getDebtsForMonth

SELECT date, amount, name AS description, paid_by, id, user_id
            FROM debts 
JOIN debtors ON debts.id=debtors.debt_id
WHERE MONTH(date) = ? and YEAR(date) = ? ORDER BY date
```

You may need to use exit; here. setting the location doesn't stop the code from running

```
public static function goToURI($uri_suffix)
{
    header("Location:" . uri_prefix . $uri_suffix);
    exit; 
}
```

It is not essential but I like to keep all my defines in uppercase

```
define('URI_PREFIX', "/coloc-web");
```

That should be enough to get your going for now.